# WIX based MSI does not self elevate

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I just watched at a customer site the execution of an MSI of ours that needs elevation, because it is a per machine install. The operator at the customer site was logged in as a consent administrator (i.e. with a restricted admin token) and simply launched the msi package of ours with a double click, went through the UI pages in order to finally hit the "Install" button on the standard WIX "Ready to install" page. What you would normally expect now is an elevation prompt, so the per machine install can be performed. What happened today when I observed this, was an attempt to perform the installation without administrative permissions, which surprised me. The install soon showed an error message stating "insufficient privileges" and a rollback was performed.

I have never observed such behaviour before. What could be the reason that the install does not "self elevate", i.e. does not show an elevation prompt after hitting the button "Install"? Is there any windows configuration setting that causes this behaviour? The computer in question was running Windows Server 2016, in case that matters.

Any help appreciated,

--
Stefan

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the MSI package was successfully executed afterwards by way of launching it from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: what about Package attributes? which ones are set?

Comment: Get a verbose log; MSI adds a lot of logging around UAC.